# MyCommand.Fill(DtSet) does not work. Why?

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledbconnection

I am trying to use OleDb to populate a DataSet, but it does not seem to work.
I got the code from a website, and know very little about Connection.
I program in VB.NET (2010) and Excel 2016.
What the code does: It inserts cell data in an Excel file using OLEDB.

I program in VB.NET (2010), and modified the code slightly to fit my needs.

Here is the full code:

```
Private Sub AdxRibbonButton16_OnClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
   ByVal control As AddinExpress.MSO.IRibbonControl, _
   ByVal pressed As System.Boolean) _
   Handles AdxRibbonButton16.OnClick

        Try

            Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

            Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet

            Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

            Dim DataGridView1 As New DataGridView

            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _
            ("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='F:\testfile.xlsx'; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")

            MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)

            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable")

            DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet

            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)  '// seems problem is here

            DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)

            MyConnection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Expected Results: The contents of the Excel File should be sent to the DataGrid.

Actual Results: Nothing Happens

Error Message: No Error message. Just nothing happens when I click my button.

Comment: After setting the `DateGridView1.DataSource`, you need to call `DataGridView.DataBind()`.

Comment: You should consider naming your variables more appropriately. "MyCommand" suggests it's a Command type, but surprise! it's actually a DataAdapter.

Comment: Hi, Filburt Thanks for reply. When I add this line: DataGridView1.DataBind(), I get error message: 'DataBind' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'

Comment: I dont think thats the problem anyway. Please show where you add this DataGridView1 control  into a control collection `Dim DataGridView1 As New DataGridView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to take a shot in the dark and say remove this line

```
Dim DataGridView1 As New DataGridView
```

If by chance it says "DataGridView1" is not declared, then drag a DataGridView from the toolbox onto the form

Alternatively, add the DataGridView you are creating to a control collection

```
Form1.Controls.add(DataGridView1)
```

Comment: Hi, Mr.Tripody. You are right. The line: "Dim DataGridView1 As New DataGridView " was not present in the code given by the web site. I added it because it says "DataGridView1 is not declared". OK - So I drag a DataGridView from ToolBox onto ADD-IN EXPRESS Form (I use Add-In Express - it's like VSTO). Now, do you have to set properties? Just pretend I am not using Add-In Express, but I'm using a Windows Form. I use Add-in Express only to design the Excel Ribbon.

Comment: I am not sure what Add-In Express is. What happens when you run it with dragging the dgv from toolbox?

Comment: Add-In Express is a third party software used to extend Office. I use it uniquely to design a beautiful Excel Ribbon, with beautiful icons on the Ribbon. If I mention it, people reading my question may shy away ... Just ignore it. My real programming is done in Visual Studio. You told me to drag a DataGridView on my Windows Form. As I use Add-in Express, I drag the DGV on my designer instead.  My question is: Suppose you have dragged the DGV on a Windows Form, then what properties must you set? and what other code must you write?  Don't worry, I will do everything over using a WIN FORM.

Comment: That's it. you are already setting the Datasource `DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)`

Comment: Mr. Tripoldi,  I will retry the example using a Windows Form tomorrow morning, and will let you know how it goes. Thanks, Leon

Comment: Hi, Mr Tripoldi     I retried the example this morning using Wndows Forms. I added the Data Grid View as you told me. Now, it works well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LeonLai Good to hear, my friend. Please check the answer as answered if this has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the DataGridView1 at design time. I simplified things a bit using a DataTable instead of a DataSet and a Command instead of a DataAdapter. The Using blocks will ensure the database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using MyConnection As New OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='F:\testfile.xlsx'; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        Using MyCommand As New OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
            MyConnection.Open()
            dt.Load(MyCommand.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: I used to put in that extra effort and point out better practices, gets exhausting...

Comment: @Mr.Tripodi Agreed. I keep trying because it is very important to close an dispose. Also when parameters are called for, I like to point out protecting the database. Since retirement I have a bit more time to provide answers with the extra details. :-)

Comment: Cheers to you, maam! Someones got to do it. On that note, referring to your example, I generally include `MyConnection.Close` after the Load method. I assume that disposing the connection via Using Block closes that for you? Sounds about right.

Comment: Right on! Using will close and dispose.

Answer (score -2):

This code fills a dataset, then a table but its in mysql you need to some changes to work with OLeDb but the vb.net part is the same

```
Dim ds1 As New DataSet
    con.Open()
    Try
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM `modes`", con)
    Catch ex As Exception
        '   s.WriteLine(Now & " The Mysql query is not possible to run down")
    End Try
    ds1.Clear()
    da.Fill(ds1)
    Dim table As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
```

Then to fill up a datagridview use this

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = table
```

I hope this will going to help.

But I strongly suggest to find the problem use breakpoints

Comment: This is a poor representation of ADO.Net to fill a datatable

Comment: You don't need to open the connection when you use the DataAdapter.Fill method

Comment: Thanks to all those who replied to my question. I have taken good note of your suggestions. My problem is solved.    Leon